# why the def function does not calculate the same answer with my last print row?

Tags: python

Just want to know why the last two commands have different returns
The return should come out with the value 600 rather than 100 for the exchange function.

```
unit ={"HKD":1, "USD":7.8, "CAN":6}
price = 100

for cur, rate in unit.items():
    print (cur, rate)

def exchange(price, cur):
  for (cur, rate) in unit.items():
    if cur=="HKD":
      exp = unit["HKD"]*price
    elif cur=="USD":
      exp = unit["USD"]*price
    else:
      exp = unit["CAN"]*price
    return print(exp)

exchange(100, "CAN")
print(unit["CAN"]*price)
```

Comment: you don't want to do `return print(exp)` you want to do `return exp`

Comment: that code is also wasting a dictionary… just access the dictionary. Dont loop on it. And it will work

Comment: In `exchange` you use `cur` for both the input parameter and for iterating over the keys of your dict in the for-loop. Change one of them to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the dictionary properly:

```
def exchange(price, cur):
   return unit[cur]*price
```

Why your code doesn't work? Beside the inefficient aspect, you're shadowing your `cur` parameter when loopîng on the dictionary keys.

Always ask yourself "why am I looping on a dictionary to perform a lookup when a dictionary is *made* for lookup without loops"

Answer (score 1):

Update your function, it should just return the exp rather then print

```
def exchange(price, cur):
    for (cur, rate) in unit.items():
        if cur == "HKD":
            exp = unit["HKD"] * price
        elif cur == "USD":
            exp = unit["USD"] * price
        else:
            exp = unit["CAN"] * price
        return exp
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same name *cur* as a function parameter as well as the iterator. Hence the parameter passed into the function is no longer the value of the variable *cur*.

In the first iteration of the loop the value of *cur* becomes "HKD" which causes the first if statement to be correct. It will calculate *exp = unit["HKD"]*price* which is equal to 100.

Also, in your code the return statement is inside the for loop and hence in the first iteration itself the looping stops and the value of exp is 100 when it is printed.

This problem can be rectified as follows:

```
unit ={"HKD":1, "USD":7.8, "CAN":6}
price = 100

for cur, rate in unit.items():
    print (cur, rate)

def exchange(price, curr):
    for (cur, rate) in unit.items():
        if curr=="HKD":
            exp = unit["HKD"]*price
        elif curr=="USD":
            exp = unit["USD"]*price
        else:
            exp = unit["CAN"]*price
        return print(exp)

exchange(100, "CAN")
print(unit["CAN"]*price)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining "cur" variable again in for loop in your function. In another sense, you have defined cur="can" while starting function, when python enter the function you have over-write cur variable as defining it again in for loop.

I guess it will work!